# Flutter code "Navigator.pop(context);" undefiend i don't know why

Tags: flutter, webview

am want to config back button on my device ,
I have problem undefined "Navigator.pop(context);" in this code any one can edit to me .thank you

```
import 'dart:js';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  void backButton() {
     Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        backButton();
        return Future.value(false);
      },
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
        home: Scaffold(
          body: WebView(
            initialUrl: "https://halgoom.com",
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think `context` is not provided where you are calling it.(the backButton() function I mean)

Comment: You use `StatelessWidget` which does not have its own class scoped `context`. You should pass `context` as parameter of your `backButton` function or call `Navigator.pop` inside `onWillPop` callback.

Comment: @Prostandy If an answer fixed your issue. Remember to mark it as correct, to help future users with the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the `context` to your method that's outside the build method. It should fix your issue.

```
void backButton(context) {
  Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

---

```
backButton(context);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `context` is undefined because you don't have any `BuildContext context` in your `MyApp`. Your context variable is inside your `Widget Build method` .
Instead of making a function to call `Navigator.pop()` `void backButton(){...}`, just place it inside your `onWillPop:(){}` function:

```
 onWillPop: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        return Future.value(false);
      },
```

By default, onWillPop will do `Navigator.pop(context);` if you return true. So instead of calling Navigator.pop() in your onWillPop, just do this:

```
 onWillPop: () =>true,
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pop( inside the onWillPop fonction. It's redudant. Just perform the action.
The fact is that onWillpop already pop...

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass context to backbutton method

```dart
void backButton(BuildContext context){ 
    Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

And pass the context while calling method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need the `import 'dart:js';`
Bet it was added in an attempt to fix the 'context' problem.

Then I'd just put the

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

into the actual place where you call backButton();
Having it as a separate function serves no purpose and the code will be shorter and easier to read in future. On the other hand, if you absolutely need it separated, you can, as others here suggest, pass in context to this function.